# How do I check if a username is taken with parse?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm a little unsure how to set up the query for this. I can only find solutions in php or javascript. Please help!

Comment: are the usernames stored in the parse class..? and before adding one more username, you want to check whether that username already exists in the parse class or not??

Comment: Just realized how bad of a title that was. I'm trying to make it to where if i try and sign up with an already existing username i get an error instead of just adding users with the same usernames.

Comment: not only the title is bad... we have no clue of what you are doing, what you have tried, where the code would go... show what you have!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code snippet which is used to check whether some username already exits in the parse class or not

```
/* Checks Is Username Already Exists
        Take - username
        Return - Bool (True/False) */

    func checkIsUserExists(username: String, completion: ((isUser: Bool?) -> Void)!) {

        var isPresent: Bool = false;

        let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "your_class_name")
        query.whereKey("your_key", equalTo:username)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                if (objects!.count > 0) {
                    isPresent = true;
                }

            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }

            completion(isUser: isPresent);
        }
    }
```